# Find/Replace with regular expressions in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, regex

Using Sharepoint Designer 2007.  I have the following block of code taken from a C# app:

```
sbuilder.Append("x");
sbuilder.Append("y");
sbuilder.Append("z");
```

and so on.  I'm translating it to Javascript.  I would like to change each `sbuilder` reference to just a regular string concatenation, e.g.

```
s += "x";
s += "y";
s += "z";
```

Using regular expressions with Find/Replace, I can set the Find expression to:

```
sbuilder[.]Append[(].*[)]
```

but how do I build the Replace expression so that the inner content of the parentheses is preserved?

Answer (score 0):

Find

```
sbuilder[.]Append[(]{.*}[)]
```

Replace

```
s += \1
```

You can use {} to specify which substring you want to use in the replace. 
Adding another {} would work too, and you can use \2 to use that substring.